# RoR making a variable available to application.html.erb so it is in all views on a header

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, variables

I have a variable I want to access in my application.html.erb so it is available to all views.  I know I can go in and add it to each controller and add it to each function so it is available to index, show, etc.  However, that is crazy.  If I want it to be in a header I should be able to access it in the application.html.erb file so it is in all my views.  An example of one of my controllers it is working in...

```
     def index
    if session[:car_info_id]
      @current_car_name = current_car.name
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @miles }
    end
  end
```

Here is my function in applicationcontroller:

```
  private   

  def current_car
    CarInfo.find(session[:car_info_id])
  end
```

If I try to add @current_car_name = current_car.name to my applicationcontroller so the variable is available to my application.html.erb it bombs with a Routing to current_car error.  I know the function works because if I call it in a different controller it works fine and I can access the variable produced in that index view or whatever.  Just need to know how to call the function once and have the variable accessible to all views since it will be in my header.  I could put the information in a session variable but I read somewhere you should limit session variables to ids and generate the other needed information from those ids.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You shouldn't make the method private. The application controller is always a base class of another controller and therefore private methods won't be available. Private methods of a base class are not available in the sub class. Other than this, I recommend you to follow Dylan Markow's advice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add a line like this to your `application_controller.rb` file and you will have access to `current_car` in your views.

```
helper_method :current_car
```

If you really wanted an instance variable, you could put a `before_filter` in your application as follows. Then both your controllers and views will have access to the `@current_car` variable.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :get_current_car
  def get_current_car
    @current_car = CarInfo.find(session[:car_info_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did option one and it worked.  Is there any reason that you know of to use one option over the other?

Comment: @Xaxum This answer is almost a year late, but for any future visitors:  helper_methods are called each time they are used in the view, whereas before_filters are called once before the view is executed.  I would use a before_filter for this so that we don't need to keep looking up the CarInfo multiple times.